# How to split the url in the render method?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to display only the "repoName" from the url, is there any way to split it inside the render method.
or there is any other way to achieve this functionality.

```
export default class A extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            ....
            ....


        };
    }

render() {
   ...
   ...

 return (
  <div>
     ...
     ...

     <span className="abc">
        {/*{item.repo} conatins https://github.com/github/repoName */}
        {item.repo}
     </span>

     ...
     ...
  </div>
  )

 }
}
```

Comment: `{}` inside these

Comment: @GermaVinsmoke can you explain little bit more.thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will get your desired result.

```
<span className="abc">
    {/*{item.repo} conatins https://github.com/github/repoName */}
    {item.repo.split('/')[4]} //repoName
 </span>
```

Comment: [4] better use `pop()`